# How to export data from Spark SQL to CSV

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, export-to-csv, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

This command works with HiveQL:

```
insert overwrite directory '/data/home.csv' select * from testtable;
```

But with Spark SQL I'm getting an error with an `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl` stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported language features in query:
    insert overwrite directory '/data/home.csv' select * from testtable
```

Please guide me to write export to CSV feature in Spark SQL.

Comment: This question/answer not solves the problem for Spark 2.x... the real problem is **to export to standard CSV  format**.  Please [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58142220/287948).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use below statement to write the contents of dataframe in CSV format
`df.write.csv("/data/home/csv")`

If you need to write the whole dataframe into a single CSV file, then use
`df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/data/home/sample.csv")`

For **spark 1.x,** you can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to write the results into CSV files

Below **scala** snippet would help

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
// sc - existing spark context
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM testtable")
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/data/home/csv")
```

To write the contents into a single file

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
// sc - existing spark context
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM testtable")
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/data/home/sample.csv")
```

Comment: I tried the coalesce thing you mentioned. It creates a directory at the specified path with a "part" file and a file called "_SUCCESS". Do you know of a way to actually only get the one file?

Comment: No, I think there is no way to do it.

Comment: it will not be local file but  hdfs file

Comment: I found a bug in this code, my original directory with partitions csv has 1 extra column when compared to the single csv generated by this code. I know the code works for trivial cases but my last 2 columns were of the format `concat('"', concat_ws(",", collect_list(some_column)), '"')` which worked fine on insert overwrite but not when I selected all the columns and wrote to this format, even the header was correct but it incorrectly identified the second last column values to fill both and ignored the rest

Comment: This is how my csv partitons looked before `"USR",0,0,""css","shell","html","python","javascript"","381534,3960,1683,229869,1569090"` and this is how they look like now `"\"USR\"",0,0,"\"\"css\"","\"shell\""`

Comment: I fixed it following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395363/how-to-include-double-quotes-in-spark-sql-concat

Comment: `repartition(1)` might be faster than `coalesce(1)`, especially if there's heavy computation beforehand.

Answer (score 50):

Since Spark `2.X` `spark-csv` is integrated as [native datasource](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html). Therefore, the necessary statement simplifies to (windows)

```
df.write
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("file:///C:/out.csv")
```

or UNIX

```
df.write
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("/var/out.csv")
```

---

Notice: as the comments say, it is creating the directory by that name with the partitions in it, not a [standard CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). This, however, is most likely what you want since otherwise your either crashing your driver (out of RAM) or you could be working with a non distributed environment.

Comment: Hi all, Is there a way to replace the file as it fails when it tries to rewrite the file.

Comment: Sure ! `.mode("overwrite").csv("/var/out.csv")`

Comment: In Spark 2.x it is creating the directory by that name. Any help?

Comment: My guess is that your partitions are inside that directory.

Comment: But **it is not a standard CSV file**, it is producing a folder with strange files (!). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58142220/287948

Comment: If you're using Spark because you're working with "big" datasets, you probably don't want to anything like `coalesce(1)` or `toPandas()` since that will most likely crash your driver (since the whole dataset has to fit in the drivers RAM). On the other hand: If your data does fit into the RAM of a single machine - why are you torturing yourself with distributed computing?

Answer (score 32):

The answer above with spark-csv is correct but there is an issue - the library creates several files based on the data frame partitioning. And this is not what we usually need. So, you can combine all partitions to one:

```
df.coalesce(1).
    write.
    format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
    option("header", "true").
    save("myfile.csv")
```

and rename the output of the lib (name "part-00000") to a desire filename.

This blog post provides more details: https://fullstackml.com/2015/12/21/how-to-export-data-frame-from-apache-spark/

Comment: One can add model as well, if one wishes to keep writing to an existing file.           `resultDF.repartition(1).write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("s3://...")`

Comment: `coalesce(1)` requires the dataset to fit into the heap of a single machine and will most likely cause issues when working with large datasets

Comment: @DmitryPetrov Do we need to mention write.format("com...") option when including coalesce option ?

Comment: @JKC Yes, coalesce(1) just repartitions to a single partition (file).

Comment: @DmitryPetrov I understand that coalesce(1) just repartitions it to a single partition file but do we need to explicitly mention the write.format option in Spark 2.x when we use coalesce option ?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to map over the DataFrame's RDD and use mkString:

```
  df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString(","))
```

As of Spark 1.5 (or even before that)
`df.map(r=>r.mkString(","))` would do the same
if you want CSV escaping you can use apache commons lang for that. e.g. here's the code we're using

```
 def DfToTextFile(path: String,
                   df: DataFrame,
                   delimiter: String = ",",
                   csvEscape: Boolean = true,
                   partitions: Int = 1,
                   compress: Boolean = true,
                   header: Option[String] = None,
                   maxColumnLength: Option[Int] = None) = {

    def trimColumnLength(c: String) = {
      val col = maxColumnLength match {
        case None => c
        case Some(len: Int) => c.take(len)
      }
      if (csvEscape) StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(col) else col
    }
    def rowToString(r: Row) = {
      val st = r.mkString("~-~").replaceAll("[\\p{C}|\\uFFFD]", "") //remove control characters
      st.split("~-~").map(trimColumnLength).mkString(delimiter)
    }

    def addHeader(r: RDD[String]) = {
      val rdd = for (h <- header;
                     if partitions == 1; //headers only supported for single partitions
                     tmpRdd = sc.parallelize(Array(h))) yield tmpRdd.union(r).coalesce(1)
      rdd.getOrElse(r)
    }

    val rdd = df.map(rowToString).repartition(partitions)
    val headerRdd = addHeader(rdd)

    if (compress)
      headerRdd.saveAsTextFile(path, classOf[GzipCodec])
    else
      headerRdd.saveAsTextFile(path)
  }
```

Comment: While this is the simplest answer (and a good one), if you're text has double-quotes, you'll have to account for them.

Comment: Simply getting the error after create RDD for the table

scala>   df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString(","));
<console>:18: error: value rdd is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
                df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString(","));

Answer (score 2):

With the help of spark-csv we can write to a CSV file.

```
val dfsql = sqlContext.sql("select * from tablename")
dfsql.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("output.csv")`
```

Comment: No, it is not a real CSV file, the result **output.csv** is a folder.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests this is not a supported feature in the query language. But you can save a DataFrame in any format as usual through the RDD interface (`df.rdd.saveAsTextFile`). Or you can check out https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv.

Comment: scala> df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/data/home.csv")
<console>:18: error: value write is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
Do I need to build current jar with databricks package again?

Comment: `DataFrame.write` was added in Apache Spark 1.4.0.

Answer (score -3):

IN DATAFRAME:

```
val p=spark.read.format("csv").options(Map("header"->"true","delimiter"->"^")).load("filename.csv")
```