# saving dataframes as texfile without converting to RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]I have the below data frame in spark.I want to save it as text file without converting to RDD  as .rdd operation is very expensive.Please help me with solution

Comment: What do you mean it's expensive ?

Comment: I can save the data frame by converting it to RDD using Dataframe.rdd and then save the file as textfile.But i had read somewhre converting Dataframes into RDD using rdd is expensive.so i was looking for ways to save dataframes as text file without converting to RDD.

Comment: That's doesn't answer my question but ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export data from Spark SQL to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937958/how-to-export-data-from-spark-sql-to-csv)

Comment: Thanks for answering.This link doesnot answer either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",<text delimiter>).save(<filePath>)
```

Need to import the com.databricks.spark.csv first.